# How to create VMWare Player Image with linux as the OS

Tags: vmware

How can I create an image (.iso) that contains:
  1. Base Ubuntu OS
  2. Java, CXF + some more software

I want these bundled as one VMPlayer image. How can I do this ?

Comment: I don't get your question to be honest. Could you clarify it more please?

Comment: Your question is confusion, there is no purpose on creating an iso if your deployment method is a VM image, unless you want to deploy a readonly VM, is that the point ?

Comment: @above, imagine a situation where you are traveling to a customer site for showing your product. An OS image with the product and the simulators on a USB is all you need to run via VMPlayer and test live. There are other uses also of a customized OS image

Comment: Call me stupid but that made your question worse.

Comment: Consider closing some of your open questions by accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This wiki will help you to customize the Ubuntu ISO : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationMaverick

Alternatively you can install Ubuntu in Vmware. Then after installing all required s/w you can export this Guest os to an VMPlayer image.

reference : http://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/systems-management/8252-how-to-use-vmware-player-to-create-your-own-images

Hope this helps.